# Get element instance in callback function

Tags: angular, golden-layout

I am developing an Angular library, a sort of Angular wrapper for [Golden Layout](https://golden-layout.com/).
I created an interface, called `ActionItem`, that gives the possibility to add buttons with actions in the component tab:

```
export interface ActionItem {
    label: string;
    icon?: string;
    iconColor?: string;
    action: (...params: any[]) => any;
}
```

The problem is, as I use this interface in another interface, that I use to define the structure of the component (GoldenLayout component, not the Angular one) within the application, I don't know how to inform the `action` about the current instance of the component.

By the moment, I only managed to add an `instanceId` attribute to the resulting button, having the component (the Angular one this time) mapped by this value inside the library service. But I can't figure out how to "inject" this value inside the listener I define in `action`

Comment: Maybe you could make use of Generics types ? something like `action<T>: (object: T, ...params: any[]) => any;`

Comment: how would it actually inform about the current instance, not the type, of the component?

Comment: Well, if you set the generic type of your `action` function to be the current component ( when you call it ) . The `object` parameters will be of the type of the current component.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I solved: not the most elegant solution maybe, but it works.

I changed the `action` type to `Function`

In the service, where I create the button, I did this:

```
const _action = item.action.bind(component.instance);
 actionBtn.addEventListener('click', _action, false);
```

where `item` is `ActionItem` itself and `component` is the `ComponentRef` object representing the object being created.

In this way, defining in my application the (GoldenLayout) Component in this way:

```
 {
  ...
  component: Test1Component as Component,
  ...
  tabActions: [
    {
      label: 'Test',
      icon: 'fa fa-heart',
      action: function () { console.log(this) }
    } as ActionItem
  ]
}
```

`this` will refer to the component instance. Hope it helps someone else

Comment: I think all you needed is bind